# In Chrome DevTools, how can you tell which responses were sent using HTTP/2 server push?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, http2

HTTP/2 server push allows a server to "push" resources to the browser before the browser has actually requested them.

When using the network tab of the Chrome DevTools, how can I tell which resources were "pushed" vs. ones that were requested in the traditional way?

I know that I can enable the Protocol column in the network tab, and that shows some calls as "h2" which I assume means HTTP/2. But what do I look for to tell whether it was actually pushed?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look for `Push` in the **Initiator** column. See `image.jpg` in the screenshot below.

[image: Network Log]

Hovering over the Waterfall also shows a breakdown of the push-related activity.

[image: Waterfall]

> I know that I can enable the Protocol column in the network tab, and that shows some calls as "h2" which I assume means HTTP/2.

Yes, this is correct. `h2` stands for HTTP/2. As mentioned, the **Protocol** column is hidden by default. Right-click the table header and select **Protocol** to enable it. See [Show more information](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/#information) for an example.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, the traffic I thought was getting pushed was not in fact pushed. I'm trying to troubleshoot why HTTP/2 requests are not being successfully redirected by my Chrome extension, which uses chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener to redirect calls.